# 10 colors such that every of the M<2048 points are colored by at least one of them

Tags: combinatorics

Question: There is an arbitrary (finite) amount of colors N, and M<2048 points, each colored by at least half of the colors. Does there exists 10 colors such that every point is colored by at least one of them?

This is true for N<20, and by dichotomy the statement would have been easy to prove to be true if it was 1023 points or less, so I think the answer is no but I would need to construct a countexample

Comment: so one point can hold multiple colors? If yes, there's probably a more natural way to present the problem

Comment: Yes that's what's implicitly implied; I probably could have used a more abstract, clearer presentation

Comment: Try this: you have $2023$ subsets of $\{1...N\}$ such that each subset is of size at least $\frac{N}{2}$.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Sadly I do not remember the source of the problem; I remember reading it somewhere a few years ago but can't remember where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a counter-example. Let $\mathbb Z_2$ be the finite field of order $2$, the set $\{0,1\}$ with addition and multiplication modulo $2$.

- Points: For each nonzero $v\in (\mathbb Z_2)^{11}$, there is a point $p_v$. There are $2^{11}-1$ points.
- Colors: For each nonzero $w\in (\mathbb Z_2)^{11}$, there is a color $c_w$. There are $2^{11}-1$ colors.
- We say that point $p_v$ has color $c_w$ if and only if $v\cdot w=1$. Recall that $(v_1,\dots,v_{11})\cdot (w_1,\dots,w_{11})=v_1w_1+\dots+v_{11}w_{11}$, where the addition and multiplication is $\pmod 2$.

Each point is colored by exactly $2^{10}$ colors, which is more than half of the colors. However, given any $10$ colors, with corresponding nonzero vectors $w_1,\dots,w_{10}$, there will always exist a vector $v$ which is orthogonal to all $10$ of them, meaning that $v\cdot w_i=0$ for each $i\in \{1,\dots,10\}$. Therefore, that $v$ is not colored by any of those colors, so these $10$ colors fail to color all points.

Here is the proof that for any $10$ vectors in $(\mathbb Z_2)^{11}$, there exists a nonzero $v\in (\mathbb Z_2)^{11}$ which is orthogonal to all of them.  Consider the linear transformation $T:(\mathbb Z_2)^{11}\to (\mathbb Z_2)^{10}$, defined by $$T(v)=(v\cdot w_1,\dots,v\cdot w_{10}).$$ The rank nullity theorem implies $\dim(\text{im } T)+\dim(\ker T)=11$. Since $\dim(\text{im }T)\le 10$, we conclude $\dim(\ker T)\ge 1$, so there exists a nonzero vector $v$ for which $T(v)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; this shows that k is the minimal of the m, so any situation with 2^k-1 is such that all points are colored by a set of m colors. However, this doesn't seem to imply anything for the other number of points N other than the global minimum of colors is either $\lfloor \log_2(N)\rfloor$ or $\lceil \log_2(N)\rceil$; the similar construction but when we do not have all $2^k-1$ points gives us that if we still take all $2^k-1$ colors, then we can choose $k$ 'independent' colors such that the intersection of the orthogonal spaces is not one of our points. Got any idea?

Comment: @GuillaumeBerlat That is indeed an interesting extension. It seems much harder, and I do not have any ideas. If you are still curious, I encourage you to post the extension as a separate question, including a link to this question.

Answer (score 1):

$2023$ subsets each of size $N/2$ $\implies$ $$2023 \times N/2 = N \text{ colors each in $L_1$ points on an average}  = N \times L_1 \implies L_1 = 2023/2 = 1011$$.

Hence there is a color $c_1$ which is present in atleast $1011$ points.

Now remove these $1011$ points in which color $c_1$ is present. Now there are $2023-1011 = 1012$ points each containing $N/2$ colors. Similar to above:
$$1012 \times N/2 = N \text{ colors each in $L_2$ points on an average}  = N \times L_2 \implies L_2 = 1012/2 = 506$$.

Hence there is a color $c_2$ which is present in atleast $506$ points which are different from $1011$ points in which color $c_1$ is present.

Continuing this way, we get, color $c_1$ in $1011$ points + color $c_2$ in $506$ points + $c_3$ in $253$ points $+ 126 + 63 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1$

So totally you can satisfy your requirement with $11$ colors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what i was talking about when talking about dichotomy, but we get 11 colors and not the wanted 10 colors, and even though this method would also shows that 10 colors would be enough for 1023 points, I don't think this can be applied to solve the original problem